# After Debian system upgrade, X does not start on boot

Tags: debian, x11, xorg, gnome, gnome3

A couple of weeks ago I made a system upgrade (aptitude upgrade) on my Debian Stretch x64 system. I finished my session normally, but since then I cannot access X anymore.

When I turn on my computer, it boots up and switches to `tty7`. Then the following messages flash a few times:

```
[  OK  ] Started LSB: exim Mail Transport Agent.
[  OK  ] Reached target Multi-User System.
[  OK  ] Reached target Graphical Interface.
Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
[  OK  ] Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
```

finally they stay on the screen(s - I have two monitors) with a blinking cursor in the next line.

My graphic chip is a HD 2500 on an Intel Core i5-3470T.

The kind users of debianforum.de guided me to look the chip up with `lspci -k`. The output contains

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
            Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8H77.I Motherboard
            Kernel driver in use: i915
```

therefore it seems to be detected.

Furthermore they instructed me to control if X is running.

```
$ ps -A | grep -i x
```

shows no traces of any X process. However

```
$ ps -a | grep -i gdm
```

returns

```
782 ?    00:00:00 gdm3
```

so gdm3 seems to be running.

```
$ X -configure
```

returns the following error

```
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: X (xorg_backtrace+0x4e) [0x562b8439985e]
(EE) 1: X (0x562b841e6000+0x1b7aa9) [0x562b8439daa9]
(EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f4bcecdb000+0x35180) [0x7f4bced10180]
(EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7f4bc8621000+0x150ba) [0x7f4bc86360ba]
(EE) 4: X (0x562b841e6000+0xb906b) [0x562b8429f06b]
(EE) 5: X (0x562b841e6000+0xb91d0) [0x562b8429f1d0]
(EE) 6: X (0x562b841e6000+0xb992a) [0x562b8429f92a]
(EE) 7: X (xf86CallDriverProbe+0x17) [0x562b84272427]
(EE) 8: X (DoConfigure+0xd7) [0x562b84271317]
(EE) 9: X (InitOutput+0x126d) [0x562b8428189d]
(EE) 10: X (0x562b841e6000+0x5bfda) [0x562b84241fda]
(EE) 11: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f4bcecfcb45]
(EE) 12: X (0x562b841e6000+0x465be) [0x562b8422c5be]
(EE)
(EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x30
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
```

This output can also be found in the lines 162-188 of my `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, which I uploaded in [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/AEEhhSgs).

How can I get X running again?

Please note, that this is a crosspost from [debianforum.de](https://debianforum.de/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=156558&start=15) and [debian-gtk-gnome](https://lists.debian.org/debian-gtk-gnome/2015/08/msg00006.html). As this seems to be a difficult problem (it could not be solved in a couple of weeks yet), I also posted it here.

Comment: I would suggest re-installing Xorg and all libraries it depends on, even if the versions haven't changed.  Also if you have any configuration files for Xorg, temporarily move them out of the way so that Xorg starts up with default settings.

Comment: If it still segfaults, try asking Xorg to use other more generic drivers.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this already but maybe I missed some packages/configuration files... Which packages/files would you purge/reinstall?

Comment: The very last thing that happened was the intel driver called a C function and then it segfaulted.  So either there's a bug in the intel driver, or the intel driver was built with a different version of the C library.  So those two packages are the first to make sure are up to date.  If you rule that out, then try something like the generic vesa driver instead of the intel driver to see if that works.  If I had more specific help I would post as an answer and not a comment ;-)  sorry.

Comment: Thank you! This approach seemed quite promising. I just purged most of my `gcc` packages as well as `xserver-xorg-video-intel` rebooted and reinstalled `tasksel-gnome` which should get all those packages back. Sadly the situation didn't change :( do you maybe have a hint for me where I could get more help?

Comment: Have you found any solution?  I get this problem if i try to boot Debian Jessie with a backported kernel 4.6.0.  The original kernel 3.16.0 boots normally.

Comment: Sorry, but this is about one year ago. I cannot remember exactly. I think I tried to save as much data as possible and then reinstalled everything.

Comment: http://www.adonespitogo.com/articles/fixed-starting-update-utmp-about-system-runlevel-changes-error-in-kali-invidia-installation/